# Can't get BlockInfo based on transaction id using Fabric Java SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using Fabric Java SDK to query my chaincode run on Hyperledger fabric v1.3.
This is steps I had tried to do:

- Create *ChannelCLient* and use method *queryByChainCode()*, I got a Collection of ProposalResponse.
- On each ProposalResponse I can get the payload and transactionID from method getTransactionID().
- After that use the transaction Id that I got from step above to query BlockInfo by method *queryBlockByTransactionID()*. 
  Because I want to get correct hash of block that contain my transacion.

But I got error message 500 *Failed to get block for txID ... error Entry not found in index*

My code look like below:

```
FabricClient fabClient = new FabricClient(adminUserContext);

        ChannelClient channelClient = fabClient.createChannelClient(Config.CHANNEL_NAME);

        Channel channel = channelClient.getChannel();
        Peer peer = fabClient.getInstance().newPeer(Config.ORG1_PEER_0, Config.ORG1_PEER_0_URL);
        EventHub eventHub = fabClient.getInstance().newEventHub("eventhub01", "grpc://localhost:7053");
        Orderer orderer = fabClient.getInstance().newOrderer(Config.ORDERER_NAME, Config.ORDERER_URL);
        channel.addPeer(peer);
        channel.addEventHub(eventHub);
        channel.addOrderer(orderer);
        channel.initialize();

        String transactionId = "";
        Logger.getLogger(QueryChaincode.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Query ");
        Collection<ProposalResponse>  responsesQuery = channelClient.queryByChainCode(chaincode, "query", args);
        for (ProposalResponse pres : responsesQuery) {
            transactionId = pres.getTransactionID();
            String stringResponse = new String(pres.getChaincodeActionResponsePayload());
            Logger.getLogger(QueryChaincode.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, stringResponse);
            System.out.println("transactionID is:" + transactionId + " chaincode id is: " + pres.getChaincodeID()
            + " peer name is: " + pres.getPeer().getName());
            result += stringResponse;
        }
        BlockInfo blockInfo = channel.queryBlockByTransactionID(transactionId);
```

Can anybody help me out how to query block based on transaction ID?

Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
BlockchainInfo blockchainInfo = channel.queryBlockchainInfo();
Long countBlock = blockchainInfo.getHeight();
blockInfoModel.setSize(countBlock.intValue());

for (int blockNumber = 0; blockNumber < countBlock; blockNumber++) {
    BlockInfo blockInfo = channel.queryBlockByNumber(blockNumber);

    blockInfoModel.getBlocks().add(new BlockInfoModel(
            String.valueOf(blockInfo.getBlockNumber()),
            blockInfo.getChannelId(),
            Hex.encodeHexString(blockInfo.getDataHash()),
            Hex.encodeHexString(blockInfo.getPreviousHash()),
            blockInfo.getTransactionCount(),
            queryDateTransactions(channel, blockInfo)
    ));

}
```